# forEach loop assigns the same random number

Tags: javascript, typescript

In typescript, I am trying to assign a random number to a property of each object in an array.  I have tried the following code

```
uniqueItems.forEach(unique => {
  unique.humanCode = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000).toString();
});
```

If I console.log inside the forEach loop, I get a different number but when I console.log the array of objects after the forEach, all of the random numbers are the same.

**Edit:** I had originally created my array of objects by using

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.quantity; i++) {
  this.uniqueItems.push(uniqueItem);
}
```

This made an array of the same object.  This meant that my array was being assigned the last random number.  I fixed this by using the spread operator when I created my array.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.quantity; i++) {
  this.uniqueItems.push({ ...this.uniqueItem });
}
```

Comment: What array of objects?

Comment: Sounds like you have an array of objects which are all the same object

Comment: Kryten is right. `uniqueItems` are not unique items. Show how you go about producing your array. You're probably adding the same object to the array many times, rather than creating new objects.

Comment: What are you printing with console.log, unique or unique.humanCode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map to iterate over your items and return a new object for each item in the array. This will also ensure you are no updating the object by reference. You should read about mutability in JavaScript. It's an important concept in JS

```
uniqueItems.map(unique => ({
  ...unique, 
  humanCode: Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000).toString(),
}));
```

Comment: My array was an array of the same object.  To fix this I used the spread operator when creating my array `{...this.uniqueItem}

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code and it works for me.

```js
let uniqueItems = [{
    humanCode: 0,
  },
  {
    humanCode: 0,
  },
  {
    humanCode: 0,
  },
]
uniqueItems.forEach(unique => {
  unique.humanCode = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000).toString();
});

console.log(uniqueItems);
```

Comment: It's not good practice to mutate the object within a forEach. You're better off to use `map` in this case.

Comment: Thank you @KiaiFighter! I just wanted to help him with his existing code.